# checking if input1 and input2 is in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to print names that equal to inputs

for example :

```
if input1 = 'A' and input2 = 'G' 
    print("Arsalan Ghasemi")
```

so my code works but for some names it's not working

if input = 'S' and second input = 'S' again
it will print 3 names that has 'S' in it even they are lowercases

here my code

```
names = ['Arsalan Ghasemi', 'Ali Bahonar', 'Negin Soleimani', 'Farzaneh Talebi', 'Sina Ghahremani',
         'Saman Sorayaie', 'Abtin Tavanmand', 'Masoud Jahani', 'Roya Pendar', 'Zeynab Arabi',
         'Amirhossein Tajbakhsh', 'Aria Irani']


def names_with_input(input1, input2):
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if input1.upper() in names[i] and input2.upper() in names[i]: 
            print(names[i])

first = input('Enter first letter: ')
last = input('Enter last letter: ')

names_with_input(first, last)
```

I thought it's only check upper cases but seems it's not
how I can fix this when inputs are 'S' and 'S', it should only give me 'Saman Sorayaie'

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `if input1.upper() in names[i] and input2.upper() in names[i] == names[i]:`, what is the intended purpose of the `== names[i]` part? How do you intend for the logic in this line to work, step by step? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to think carefully about the **exact** steps the code needs to take, step by step, in order to solve the problem.

Comment: i=0 and name[0] --> 'Arsalan Ghasemi' || is 'A' in 'Arsalan Ghasemi' ? yes okay next input Is 'G' in 'Arsalan Ghasemi' ? yes okay now print 'Arsalan Ghasemi', i am thinking wrong?

Comment: Okay, so the first part of that is covered by `if input1.upper() in names[i]`, right? And the second part is covered by `input2.upper() in names[i]`, right? And then what is this leftover `== names[i]` part for?

Comment: Oh, It was mistake when I was copy pasting it here sorry D:

Comment: Now, as far as your question goes: Is 'S' in 'Negin Soleimani'? Is 'S' in 'Negin Soleimani'? (I did not stutter; if you give two 'S' inputs, then it will try the same test twice, right?) I think it is: I think 'Soleimani' starts with an S, so I expect that 'S' will be found in 'Negin Soleimani'. So, the result is not confusing, is it? In that case - maybe this is not actually what you want to test. I think you want to test: "Is 'S' in 'Negin'? Is 'S' in 'Soleimani'?" In fact, maybe it is even more specific than that. Please try to think about it carefully.

Comment: okay i get it now thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
names = ['Arsalan Ghasemi', 'Ali Bahonar', 'Negin Soleimani', 'Farzaneh Talebi', 'Sina Ghahremani',
         'Saman Sorayaie', 'Abtin Tavanmand', 'Masoud Jahani', 'Roya Pendar', 'Zeynab Arabi',
         'Amirhossein Tajbakhsh', 'Aria Irani']


def names_with_input(input1, input2):
    for name in names:
        first_name, last_name = name.split()
        if input1.upper() == first_name[0] and input2.upper() == last_name[0] : 
            print(name)
names_with_input('s','s')
```

hope this will help for you

Comment: Use `==` instead of `in`.

Answer (score 3):

Check the initials only instead of checking if the initial occurs inside the whole name. Split the first, last using `str.split()`.

```
names = ['Arsalan Ghasemi', 'Ali Bahonar', 'Negin Soleimani', 'Farzaneh Talebi', 'Sina Ghahremani',
         'Saman Sorayaie', 'Abtin Tavanmand', 'Masoud Jahani', 'Roya Pendar', 'Zeynab Arabi',
         'Amirhossein Tajbakhsh', 'Aria Irani']


def names_with_input(input1, input2):
    for n in names:
        n1, n2 = n.split()
        if input1.upper() == n1[0] and input2.upper() == n2[0]: 
            print(n)
            break

first = input('Enter first letter: ')
last = input('Enter last letter: ')

names_with_input(first, last)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the first character of each string separated by the space between name and surname:

```
names = ['Arsalan Ghasemi', 'Ali Bahonar', 'Negin Soleimani', 'Farzaneh Talebi', 'Sina Ghahremani',
         'Saman Sorayaie', 'Abtin Tavanmand', 'Masoud Jahani', 'Roya Pendar', 'Zeynab Arabi',
         'Amirhossein Tajbakhsh', 'Aria Irani']


def names_with_input(input1, input2):
    for i in range(len(names)):
        s = names[i].split(" ")
        if input1.upper() == s[0][0] and input2.upper() == s[1][0]: 
            print(names[i])

first = input('Enter first letter: ')
last = input('Enter last letter: ')

names_with_input(first, last)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter first letter: A
Enter last letter: T
Abtin Tavanmand
Amirhossein Tajbakhsh
```

Comment: Thanks but why I can't use input1.upper() in names[i] ?

Comment: @ali-ebadi Because if one character is contained in names[i] and the other input character is the same. One will be ignored on `names[i]`